# Surjective and Injection proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $g: \mathbb{Z_{12}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{12}}$ defined by $g(x)=5x+8$. Prove $g$ is injective and surjective.

Would this be a correct proof for this?

Let $b \in \mathbb{Z_{12}}$. Let $a = \frac{b-8}{5}$. Note $a \in \mathbb{Z_{12}}$. Then $g(a)=5a+8= 5(\frac{b-8}{5}) +8 = b-8=8=b$. Therefore g(x) is surjective.

Let $c,d, \in \mathbb{Z_{12}}$. Assume $f(c)=f(d)$. Then $5c+8=5d+8$. Subtracting $8$ yields $5c=5d$. So $c=d$. Therefore, $g(x)$ is injective.

Comment: Justify writing $1/5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(12)$. Then you could just write down $g^{-1}(x)$, so that $g$ is bijective.

Comment: As long as you're clear on what $\frac{1}{5}$ means modulo $12$, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Mentioning that you can divide by $5$ because it is prime with $12$ would not harm.

Comment: The best way of proving a function is bijective (injective and surjective) is writing down its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

You have to justify why, in the ‘injection’ part, you can use the cancellation law:
$$ 5x=5y\implies x=y $$
Also for the ‘surjection’ part, avoid the fraction notation: $5$ is not an integer here. Better denote $a=5^{-1}(b-8)$, and again this requires proving $5$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$, and finding its inverse.

*Note 1*:

As @lhf pointed in his comment, it is enough to prove injectivity, since it is  a map from a finite set to a finite set with the same cardinal.

*Note 2*:
The proof may be simplified observing that it is the composition of multiplication by $5$ (which is a bijection if you show $5$ is a unit) by the translation $x\mapsto 8$, which is a bijection since  $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$ is a group for addition.

Comment: Fractional notation works just fine in my opinion.

Comment: Injective implies surjective because the sets are finite of the same size.

Comment: @lhf: Right. Don't   know why I forgot to use this even simpler argument. 'Twas late, probably.